# How can I minify Javascript code in Gitlab CI?

Tags: javascript, gitlab, webhooks, minify, gitlab-ci

I write Javascript code for the web which I usually *minify* before uploading.
I do it locally with a dedicated tool (like *UglifyJS*) but I would like to automate the process slightly using **Gitlab Continuous Integration** (because I use Gitlab on this project).

My aim seems quite simple: **use Gitlab CI to minify the code on certain events and output these files** in a convenient way for me to get them.

*However, I haven't found anything (tutorial or other) to do this yet.*

I have very little experience with Gitlab CI so I don't really know where to start but I have tried breaking that into smaller problems:
- I can't find a *simple script* that does compression/minification that I could run using Gitlab CI, it's mostly bigger utilities (YUI Compressor, Google Closure Compiler).
- If I find a way to compress the files can I push them on my repository from the CI? And if yes, *I am wondering if that's actually good practice* because that would version the minified files which is not useful.

My *best shot at something not too complicated* seems to be **Google Closure Compiler** which can be used with its API. And if I understand correctly, I could use **Gitlab's Webhooks** to make that API call (not sure exactly how I would pass the data this way but I'll see what I can do). But then, how can I read the response (Gitlab Webhooks don't seem fit for that) ?
Maybe it would be better to make these API calls in Gitlab CI directly but I am not sure how to be honest and mostly how I can get the compressed data back and what I could do with it (where to store it).

Comment: Why don't you build or search for a Docker image that minifies your Javascript? If you can do it locally, you should be able to replicate it on a Gitlab CI job.

Comment: Indeed, this looks like what I want to do! I will look into it!
I have never worked with Docker images before but I will also try to see if I can do something this way thanks.

Answer (score 4):

My answer comes a bit late but it might help others. IMO, the easiest way would be to use a dedicated tool such as [yuicompressor](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor) (also works great for CSS). Here is an example of a `gitlab-ci`:

```
before_script:
  - apt-get update && apt-get install -y -qq sshpass
  - apt-get install -y -qq default-jdk
  - mkdir yuicompressor
  - wget -P yuicompressor/ https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/releases/download/v2.4.8/yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar

deploy_production:
  stage: deploy
  environment: Production
  only:
    - master
  script: 
    - java -jar yuicompressor/yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar -o '.js$:.js' src/static/js/*.js
    - export SSHPASS=$SSH_PASS
    - sshpass -e scp -o stricthostkeychecking=no -r src/* user@some_domain.net:~/www/
```

### Explanation

This pipeline **minify and replace** all the js files contained in `src/static/js/` before sending the entire project `src` to the production server with sshpass.

#### Before Script

Since gitlab runners do not have **java** by default, we install it `apt-get install -y -qq default-jdk`. We then only need to `wget` yuicompressor's jar

Hope it helps

Comment: Late but still useful thanks!
I will try this out since I have not done much on this problem.

Comment: @DylanM do not hesitate to ping me if you have any more questions

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is looking for solving this by using uglify.js in your pipeline.
You can use below code in the pipeline and get the minified code

```
minify-js:
  image: node:latest
  stage: process
  script:
    - npm install uglify-js -g
    - mkdir -p ./output
    - uglifyjs ./public/js/xxx.js -o output/xxx.min.js -c -m
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - output

deploy-dev:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - cp output/xxx.min.js public/js/xxx.min.js
```

Above yaml converts xxx.js to xxx.min.js in the minify_js task

Comment: Actually, your's is lighter/faster than my answer

Answer (score 0):

Using @hybrid approach, I adapt it to work with [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler)
Will run only if source file has changed (changes)

```
minify-js:
  image: node:latest
  stage: process
  only:
    changes:
      - "public/js/script.js"
  script:
    - npm i -g google-closure-compiler
    - google-closure-compiler --js public/js/script.js --js_output_file tmp/script.min.js --language_in=ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - tmp/script.min.js
    expire_in: 1 day

deploy-dev:
  stage: deploy
script:
    # Copy compiled script file if exist
    - test -f tmp/script.min.js && cp tmp/script.min.js public/js/script.min.js
```